# How to extract date from 2 columns in a database - on the database side - and store it in a php variable?

Tags: php, sql, database

I would like to extract the difference in days between 2 dates. My table is called `bookstakenout`

```
$dateDiff = "SELECT DATEDIFF(day, BorrowedDate, ReturnedDate) FROM bookstakenout  
             WHERE BorrowNumberID = $bnid";
```

Here is the error that I get

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2SELECT DATEDIFF(day, BorrowedDate, ReturnedDate) FROM bookstakenout WHERE BorrowNumberID = 5

Hopefully the question has been asked correctly, sorry if its not.

Comment: Please consult the *official* documentation on that function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: Plus, you may have thought that using an sql-server method also applied to MySQL https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms189794.aspx it doesn't. Which I feel is what you may have a background in working with in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Supposed to be as below:

```
$dateDiff = "SELECT DATEDIFF(BorrowedDate, ReturnedDate) FROM bookstakenout  
             WHERE BorrowNumberID = $bnid";
```

there is no day. Result will return as number of day difference. Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_datediff_mysql.asp